# How can I draw following figures by using tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I wish to draw the following figures:

1. Three circles in a row having radius 2cm, 3cm and 4cm respectively by using `tkz-euclide`.
2. Three equilaterals triangles in a row having length of sides 2cm, 3cm and 4cm respectively by using `tkz-euclide`.
3. Three squares in a row having length of sides 2cm, 3cm and 4cm respectively by using `tikz-euclide`.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,headheight=14.5pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (4,0) circle (1.5cm);
\draw (6.95,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0);
\draw (3,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,0);
\draw (7,0) -- (11,0) -- (11,4) -- (7,4) -- (7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code uses tikz and not tkz-euclide. There is not difficulty to get what you want with tikz.. You can remove ` \usepackage{tkz-euclide} \usetkzobj{all} `

Comment: radius or diameter ?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use tkz-euclide. In this case you avoid the call to tikz because euclide loads it

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \d/\x/\y in {2/-2/0,3/1/0,4/5/0}{%
        \tkzDefPoint(\x,\y){K}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[K](0:\d){M}
        \tkzDefSquare(K,M)\tkzGetPoints{N}{O}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[color=red](K,M,N,O)
        \tkzLabelSegment[below](K,M){Square side=\d cm}
      }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \d/\x/\y in {2/-2/0,3/2/0,4/6/0}{%
          \tkzDefPoint(\x,\y){J}
          \tkzDefShiftPoint[J](0:\d){L}
          \tkzDrawTriangle[equilateral,color=blue](J,L)
          \tkzLabelSegment[below](J,L){Tr. Equ. side=\d cm}
      }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
           \foreach \d/\x/\y in {1/0/0,1.5/3.5/0,2/8/0}{%
              \tkzDefPoint(\x,\y){I} \tkzDefShiftPoint[I](60:\d){T}
              \tkzDrawPoints[size=4,fill=gray](I,T) \tkzDrawSegment(I,T)
              \tkzDrawCircle[R,color=purple](I,\d cm)
              \tkzLabelCircle[R,text width=3cm,text centered]
                          (I,\d cm+1cm)(-60){Circle R=\d cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes sir , actually i want to draw all figures in a raw

Comment: i mean three circles with mentioned radius in a raw, three squares in a raw as well as equilateral triangles in a single raw.

Comment: i by mistake i add package tkz, i really want to draw by tkz-euclid

Comment: Like the output answered by flav

Comment: It's not a real problem to place objects in a row ( my english is not good I don't know what a raw is ?) You want radius =4cm but you wrote 2cm in your example

Comment: let me clear sir, raw i mean side by side

Comment: ok it's not a big problem I will my code in a moment ...

Comment: @Alian Matthes waiting for the revised code, sir

Comment: Sir, your are genius. i can't find words for thanks, thanks a lot. One more question how can i put a small dot as a center of each circle and how to draw a line segment as a radius of each circle in available code

Comment: Even i want to give proper labeling to each figures.

Comment: Please help me on my last two comments. its a humble request to you

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,headheight=14.5pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (4,0) circle (1.5cm);
\draw (6.95,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (3,0) rectangle (6,3);
\draw (7,0) rectangle (11,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0cm,0cm) -- ++(0:2cm) -- ++(120:2cm) -- ++(-120:2cm);
  \draw (4cm,0cm) -- ++(0:3cm) -- ++(120:3cm) -- ++(-120:3cm);
  \draw (8cm,0cm) -- ++(0:4cm) -- ++(120:4cm) -- ++(-120:4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in the circle, how can i put (draw) a dot as a center of circle and one line segment (radius) of the circle.

Comment: yes sir, its exactly what i need but i am looking for same out put by using tkz-euclid